# Launch SCORM package on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, scorm

I am pretty new to SCORM and I would like my iOS application written in Objective - C to be able to display and read a local SCORM package stored on the device.

I have read through articles and seem like I cannot find any resources to do this. Are there any libraries that allow me to do so?

I have read this question:

[Playing SCORM on Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392554/playing-scorm-on-android-devices)

But I do not know how to connect to the SCORM API and is it possible to do so with the same method on iOS device?

I am also aware that there is something called the Tin Can API. Is it necessary to convert a SCORM package into Tin Can API and display it on iOS app?

I am really new to SCORM if I have any misconceptions about it please tell me.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If you want more details in general about SCORM you might contact info@scorm.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assisted with Angular, but I would imagine iOS UIWebView would need to expose the SCORM Runtime so the content can communicate with it. I've seen some references of a JavaScript bridge.
I've seen other examples of just running a page, then a IFRAME for the content as another possible workaround.

You've need a Javascript version of the SCORM Runtime API for SCORM 1.2 or SCORM 2004.  This typically means using Brian's solution mentioned, another 3rd Party, or rolling your own. Depending on what features you need to support that may answer your time-to-market / cost.

As far as the TinCan API that content typically communicates with a endpoint (server) defined by the content.  So unless you have control of the authored content you may not have a choice what thats doing (someone can correct me if I'm wrong).

GL

Answer (score 0):

In general the two pieces required to make this work are to be able to load the web pages found in the manifest as described by the answers to the other question and to provide the JavaScript API which the content uses to communicate to the LMS. Generally the harder part here is the API portion which involves reading, understanding, and then implementing the SCORM runtime API specification. There is an existing product to do this for iOS/Android, for more info see https://scorm.com/i-want-to-build-a-mobile-app/

The Tin Can API, generally now referred to as the xAPI (or Experience API) is not necessary in this case. The xAPI is a specification that describes a data structure and communications protocol that can be leveraged in a mobile app (and otherwise) to capture learning data. It does not include a specification for packaging, launching, and specific data points like with SCORM.

Which solution is right is generally more use case dependent and more information would be needed to tell.